# Этимология слова "на" (в смысле "бери!")

Tags: этимология, грамматика

Я тут задумался над тем, чем является слово "на", с точки зрения грамматики, когда оно применяется в выражении "на, возьми".

Мне кажется, что это глагол или, по крайней мере, то, что осталось от какого-то древнего глагола, вроде "нать", в смысле "давать".

Ведь добавляем же мы окончание "-те" во множественном числе: "на**те**" (по аналогии с "возьми — возьми**те**", "держи — держи**те**"), "на — на**те**".

Answer (score 1):

Это общеиндоевропейское междометие, значения которого изменились в разных языках. Возможно, связано со словом *он* или испытало его влияние.

Вот что пишет Фасмер:
на III межд. на́-ка, на́тко, 2 л. мн. на́те, укр. на, на́те, блр на, на́це, болг. на «глядь» (Младенов 314), сербохорв. нȃ, словен. nȃ, nаtе, слвц. nа, чеш. nа, nаtе, польск. nа, nać родственно лит. nà, лтш. nа «ну», др.-инд. nā́-nā «в разных местах, по-разному», греч. νή, беот. аркад. νεί «право, воистину», лат. nē «да, так, поистине» наряду с греч. ναί, лат nае; см. Траутман, ВSW 192; Зубатый, LF 37, 223, 227; Перссон, IF 2, 204 и сл.; Соболевский, ЖМНП, 1886, сент., стр. 146; Вальде-Гофм. 2, 150; Буазак 655 и сл. Существуют попытки сблизить с он.

Comment: Если ссумировать (Фасмер плюс собственная т.з.), каков ответ?

Comment: Если эти слова выражают суть, и они не уводят в сторону от вопроса, в том числе и о выражении «на, возьми», то почему из комментария их не ввести в текст ответа?

Comment: В междометиях "те" появляется, но как сокращение от слова "тебе". Например: "вот те раз" - как сокращенная форма от "вот тебе раз". Или "вот те бабушка и Юрьев день" вместо "вот тебе бабушка и Юрьев день". Ни в одном из приведенных примеров "-те" не образует повелительную форму в множественном числе. Не знаю как в остальных славянских языках, но в русском она явно обозначает множественное число - хотя бы потому, что применима при вежливом обращении: "нате, возьмите пожалуйста эту книгу".

Answer (score 0):

В фундаментальном словаре Трубачёва "Этимологический словарь славянских языков" слову "на" посвящено две с лишним страницы со следующим выводом в конце:

> Несомненность дейктической, местоименной природы (указательное и.-е.
>   ***an-**) побуждает не разрывать этимологически, а объединять случаи вроде русск. предл. **на** и частицы **на 'возьми'**, что и сделано
>   выше.

Я не достаточно квалифицирован, чтобы пересказать коротко это самое "выше", но оставлю в качестве ответа на вопрос ссылку на этот словарь. Там же есть ссылки на другие, ещё более подробные, этимологические словари.

**Мне кажется, что это глагол или, по крайней мере, то, что осталось от какого-то древнего глагола, вроде "нать", в смысле "давать".**

Это ранее было междометием, а не глаголом. Поэтому указанная связь происхождения от глагола мне представляется сомнительной.

Comment: **на** не может быть междометием, потому что междометия не меняются по числам, а в данном случае имеется форма во множественном числе: **нате**. Ну или хотя бы приведите аргумент в пользу того, что **нате** это не множественное число, а что-то другое.

Comment: @Jaroslav **На** — частица. Я имел в виду происхождение от междометия. И связь с глаголом имел в виду тоже этимологическую, которую Вы предположили. Я откорректировал ответ. В любом случае я не настаиваю на своей правоте, но мне представляется, что если имеются очень давние корни от междометия (так указано в словаре), то надеяться на ещё более давнюю связь с глаголом не стоит. Скорее уж наоборот.

Comment: "...но оставлю в качестве ответа на вопрос ссылку на этот словарь". Очень бы хотелось видеть обещанное.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Я имел в виду ссылку на название :) А вообще для поиска научных книг есть специальный [научный поисковик](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/) — там и это, и многое другое можно найти.